# scp - permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, scp

I am able to ssh into a remote server

```
ssh -i "C:\Users\kong\Documents\prl.ppk" haziq@10.0.1.111
```

but not able to scp

```
scp -i "C:\Users\kong\Documents\prl.ppk" kong@10.0.1.111:~/home_nfs/kong/script/train.py "./script"
```

but get this message

```
Load key "C:\\Users\\kong\\Documents\\prl.ppk": invalid format
Permission denied (publickey).
```

How do I fix this? This is my prl.ppk file.

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: rsa-key-20210426
Public-Lines: 6
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAliFI5IDLY4pOPuWhetezPDd7kgh5SeT9sWJq
J9QPnt6rKtzV+W+MABq7PujdwgYdg6ulfHRy+274vWc4Iv1fMd25pRA9dGsht91s
OaBdcw3tX8jEJ10OeLpm+7erROuSc6n5vlYuY5LD90RIB+MG3aoXOGKT+h3oMhr+
N3+mAKhXIEy272xisHOzsmTrPhAsMmoRNDZ1XhRiLm67SHv0HK9ZALxE6yL6TbtM
n2S8rZFtxRTl3QEa2CsmOqluGyybyFGIKrS92drmZOc4rF0oNLdzfoS01hKHD2EZ
Xls3UhK/URttzcIql/7v9tXvknoUZRj+VSbCJqzjiCK0/so8Xw==
Private-Lines: 14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Private-MAC: 9beae1b5c93534406ee8feceace093bc8972728a
```

Comment: You just published your private key.   Thats like advertising your password.  You likely need to generate a new key and revoke permissions on all systems  using it.

Answer (score 0):

If the server runs OpenSSH server, you will need to convert the key into OpenSSH acceptable formats. The Putty format (ppk) is not accepted.

You can do that in the PuTTYgen tool.

Comment: thanks but why am I able to ssh into the server? Do the two commands accept different types of ppk files?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Kong Ponder on: are `scp` and `ssh` from the same source; i.e. same person or company has created them? Same software package?

Comment: @Kong You can run `ssh -v ...` to see verbose output and figure out whether the `ssh` command actually uses the ppk key you provided. I suspect that the ssh command is part of Windows Powershell. Maybe it takes ppk key.